# Issue with Firebase dynamic links

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

We are trying to use dynamic links for deep linking. The link is behaving normally.

However, on click, it is not hitting the userActivity restorationHandler method in the app.

We have followed all the steps mentioned in the document,  and the output of diagnostics is below

```
---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output start 

version 12.1.1,  model iPhone Current date 2018-12-13 05:08:44 +0000 Device locale en-IN (raw en_IN), timezone Asia/Kolkata    Specified custom URL scheme is dev.XXX.xxx and Info.plist contains such scheme in CFBundleURLTypes key.    AppID Prefix: XXXX, Team ID: XXXX, AppId Prefix equal to Team ID: YES performDiagnostic completed successfully! No errors found.

---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output end -------- 
Firebase Dynamic Links framework version 3.3.0 System information: OS
iOS, OS
```

There is a warning in the dynamic link console regarding app ID prefix.

> iOS app ‘com.xxx.ios’ lacks App ID Prefix. UniversalLinks is not enabled for the app.

We have cross checked our team ID and it seems to be fine.

Could someone please help us resolve this?

Comment: Does it hit 'application(_ app: open url: options:)'?

Comment: @Vitalii No, it doesn't

Comment: do you have applinks:<yourdomain>.page.link in project's Capabilities > Associated Domains? You can check that the associated domains file (automatically generated by Firebase) works correctly using this tool: https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/ If it doesn't - double-check your dynamic links setup in firebase.

Comment: can you double check to what app you've included the team ID? Based on the diagnostics output, it doesn't have any issues with Dynamic Links (just a wild guess). On the other hand, the warning in dynamic link  regarding app ID prefix points to other app (just also a wild guess). By any chance, do you have multiple iOS apps in your Firebase project?

Comment: @Vitalii Yes. We have included it in Associated Domains. The configuration of the file looks fine

Comment: @dev.for.fun We do have multiple apps. But, all of them have the same teamID.

Comment: You've double-checked team ID (aka App ID prefix) in Firebase console > Settings > General > Your apps > iOS apps > <appID> > Team ID, right? Maybe you are using older GoogleService-Info.plist. Try re-download it, just in case.

Comment: @Vitalii We did cross check the teamID. We are using the correct value itself. We also tried updating the GoogleService-Info.plist like you suggested. No luck :|

Comment: Same issue here.. Setup Team ID, still get warning when I debug the Dynamic Link. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Dirk We got it to hit the method somehow. Don't recall what the issue was. 
The warnings are still there though.

Comment: @Dirk Any success?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same issue.
So, I asked Firebase team, got answers and fixed the problem.
Here is the solution.

> Looks like you’ve encountered an issue while debugging your Firebase
>   Dynamic Link. Just to share, when adding an iOS app to a Firebase
>   project, an OAuth client ID is automatically generated for it in it’s
>   associated Cloud project. Deleting the app doesn't remove its
>   corresponding client IDs, which can cause issues for the dynamic link.
>   Here are the steps to change or delete the package name/bundle ID for
>   the client IDs:
>
> 1. Access the project on the [Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)
> 2. Go to APIs and Services > Credentials
> 3. Identify the client ID with the conflicting package name/bundle ID in the name (ex: [Android/iOS] client for 
>      (auto created by Google Service)
> 4. Edit the package name/bundle ID and save changes or delete the OAuth client ID

Comment: Thanks in our case we had two different, credentials. After we deleted the "old credentials" - that normally not get hitted anymore - the error was gone

Comment: Is it safe to delete the OAuth client ID

Comment: Please accept this answer OP. This saved my life. Why is this not documented in the Firebase docs??

Comment: I have no idea how would one deduce this solution without directly contacting the support team. No mention of this in Firebase documentation indeed.

Comment: This worked for us, we had an old bundleID lying around and deleting it helped us remove that universal link error showing up on the fallback url

Comment: This worked for me, I simply deleted the one that was auto created by google. And it worked immediately.