# Why is universal links not enabled for iOS Firebase dynamic link?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have generated a dynamic link in Firebase, but it shows the following error.

```
iOS app 'org.domain' lacks App ID Prefix. UniversalLinks is not enabled for the app.
```

In the API response I get the below error.

```
{
    "warningCode": "UNRECOGNIZED_PARAM",
    "warningMessage": "iOS app 'org.domain' lacks App ID Prefix. UniversalLinks is not enabled for the app. [https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug#ios-team-id-absent]"
},
```

I have iOS Team ID, app store id added in the Firebase project. The app has the bundle identifier `org.domain` format. Is that a problem? The app is published in App Store and I don't want to change the bundle ID if possible. The dynamic link opens the web page instead of the app on iOS.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase and the underlying google cloud services can get out of sync. Try the solution offered for this question:

[Issue with Firebase dynamic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755779/issue-with-firebase-dynamic-links)