# Firebase shows different bundle id in dynamic link section

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm creating an app which requires dynamic link feature.

the Android app has the id:

> com.example.example

the iOS app has the id:

> in.example.example

For some reason on link preview(debug) view it shows `iOS app 'com.exam-ple.example' lacks App ID Prefix. UniversalLinks is not enabled for the app. Learn more.`

I haven't added this id anywhere in the Firebase project.

Comment: i'm having same issue, did you got solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved this issue, by removing the app id, which I was not using. In this case the package id for android is `com.example.example` and for iOS is "in.example.example", but on GCP (Google Cloud Console) I found another id "com.exam-ple.example". So I just removed the 3rd one. and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there is multiple auth key added with different bundle id in google cloud consol which automatically generate key

please check below link for detail answer

[Issue with Firebase dynamic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755779/issue-with-firebase-dynamic-links)